# I want to check when exactly I am on a specific web page. The Website has a searchbar and through that I want to ensure the I am on the website

Tags: python, selenium

I  tried using the selenium Waits:

```
def locationchecker():  
     try:
         searchbox_identifyer = WebDriverWait(driver, 7200).until(
         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'searchTerm_Header'))
     )
     print('On homepage :)')
 except:
     print('Error')
```

The problem is, that when I invalidate the ID to  for example --> 'earchTerm-Header', it only says Error, when close the browser manually then.To sum up, I simply want that the Browser is waiting, until the element was located and if the element could not be located directly the browser waits.

Comment: Its hard to understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.

**Regarding "wrong Error":**

Please change your waiting time from 7200 to something like 20 and then try again  with your  wrong ID. (7200 = 120 minutes waiting time, quite a while :))

**Regarding "adding timestamp"**

--> Try importing time

```
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime
print('current timestamp: {}'.format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())))
```

so your complete code should look like

```
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime
def locationchecker():  
     try:
         searchbox_identifyer = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'searchTerm_Header'))
     )
     print('current timestamp / on homepage: {}'.format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())))
 except:
     print('Error')

print('current timestamp: {}'.format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())))
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, works better, but isn't the browser in this case only waiting for 20 seconds: (driver, 20) and if the element wasn't found in this 20 Seconds the browser stops waiting?

Comment: Exactly, but this is the answer to your question why you do not get the error print (because the script simply isn't executed yet. Does this make sense? Obviously you can set the waiting time to whatever you want.